# Reset button to remove all user input data

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-entry, tkinter-button

I'm having a problem with the **"Clear Data"** Button I created, and since I'm new to Tkinter, I was wondering if anyone can help me. I am trying to make the program clear the user data input once I click the button, but so far, I just can't figure this out. The code is shown below. I've been trying for a while, and still can't figure it out.

```py
global entry
entry = StringVar()

def cleardata():
    entry.delete(1.0, END)

def btn1function():
    top = tkinter.Toplevel(root)
    top.title("ADD RECORDS")
    frame = tk.Frame(top)
    bg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file="latestadrec.png")
    labl = tk.Label(frame, image=bg)
    labl.img = bg
    labl.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor='center')

    fname = tk.Label(frame, text="First Name:", font=('Bold', 16))
    fname.place(x=50, y=400)
    fnameEntry = tk.Entry(frame, textvariable=firstname, font=('Bold', 16))
    fnameEntry.place(x=220, y=400, width=180)

    lname = tk.Label(frame, text="Last Name:", font=('Bold', 16))
    lname.place(x=50, y=450)
    lnameEntry = tk.Entry(frame, textvariable=lastname, font=('Bold', 16))
    lnameEntry.place(x=220, y=450, width=180)

    address = tk.Label(frame, text="Address:", font=('Bold', 16))
    address.place(x=50, y=500)
    addressEntry = tk.Entry(frame, textvariable=address1, font=('Bold', 16))
    addressEntry.place(x=220, y=500, width=180)

    conum = tk.Label(frame, text="Contact Number:", font=('Bold', 16))
    conum.place(x=50, y=550)
    conumEntry = tk.Entry(frame, textvariable=connum, font=('Bold', 16))
    conumEntry.place(x=220, y=550, width=180)

    email = tk.Label(frame, text="Email:", font=('Bold', 16))
    email.place(x=50, y=600)
    emailEntry = tk.Entry(frame, textvariable=email1, font=('Bold', 16))
    emailEntry.place(x=220, y=600, width=180)

    petname = tk.Label(frame, text="Pet name:", font=('Bold', 16))
    petname.place(x=650, y=400)
    petnameEntry = tk.Entry(frame,textvariable=pname, font=('Bold', 16))
    petnameEntry.place(x=790, y=400, width=180)

    gender = tk.Label(frame, text="Gender:", font=('Bold', 16))
    gender.place(x=650, y=450)
    genderEntry = tk.Entry(frame,textvariable=gender1, font=('Bold', 16))
    genderEntry.place(x=790, y=450, width=180)

    breed = tk.Label(frame, text="Breed:", font=('Bold', 16))
    breed.place(x=650, y=500)
    breedEntry = tk.Entry(frame,textvariable=breed1, font=('Bold', 16))
    breedEntry.place(x=790, y=500, width=180)

    birth = tk.Label(frame, text="Birth Date:", font=('Bold', 16))
    birth.place(x=650, y=550)
    birthEntry = tk.Entry(frame,textvariable=birth1, font=('Bold', 16))
    birthEntry.place(x=790, y=550, width=180)

    problem = tk.Label(frame, text="Problem:", font=('Bold', 16))
    problem.place(x=650, y=600)
    problemEntry = tk.Entry(frame,textvariable=problem1, font=('Bold', 16))
    problemEntry.place(x=790, y=600, width=180)

    button = tk.Button(frame, text="SUBMIT DATA", command=savefile, font=('Bold', 14))
    button.place(x=300, y=700)

    button2 = tk.Button(frame, text="CLEAR DATA", command=cleardata, font=('Bold', 14))
    button2.place(x=550, y=700)

    frame.pack(pady=10)
    frame.pack_propagate(False)
    frame.configure(width=1000, height=800)
```

Comment: You need to provide a [mre].

Comment: I'm trying to place my code but it's rejecting me from placing the code saying my code is not formatted properly

Comment: Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code. Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut. For more editing help, click the [?] toolbar icon.

I don't know what seems to be the problem

Comment: I'm going to say the same thing I said yesterday: You can easily format a block of code in your question by inserting three (3) backtick characters `, followed by your code, then another three backticks on a new line. You can also just paste your code into your question, highlight the entire block, and press ctrl+k on your keyboard to format the whole block as code. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for help on formatting on StackOverflow

Comment: I'm really sorry about this mess and thank you as well always sir @Jriggles

Comment: What have you tried so far in your `cleardata` function? I'm afraid you're not likely to get much help if you're looking to have someone write code for you.

Comment: I tried to use global function that I can call inside the def cleardata function.  Tried to use this entry.delete(1.0, END) but got an error AttributeError: 'StringVar' object has no attribute 'delete'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to use the `delete` method of the `Entry` widget if you are looking to delete text, better to put all the entries inside a list and loop through them rather doing it one by one.

```
def cleardata():
    for ent in ent_list:
        ent.delete(0, 'end')

def btn1function():
    global ent_list
    ...
    ent_list = [fnameEntry, lnameEntry, ...]
```

**Or** you could also create the list in the *main part* (outside of function) and then use its `append()` method to add each entry onto the list. The first solution might be less code and more readable.

**Or** if you want to avoid globalizing the list, then pass the list as an argument instead:

```
def cleardata(ent_list):
    for ent in ent_list:
        ent.delete(0, 'end')

def btn1function():
    ...
    ent_list = [fnameEntry, lnameEntry, ...]
    
    button2 = tk.Button(..., command=lambda: cleardata(ent_list))
```

Comment: Wow! The second one works for me!!! Thank you very much sir! Really appreciated it! Have a great day!